# how to find image for computervision programs

Tags: computer-vision, face-detection, eye-tracking

hi
i'm trying some eigenvector tecniques for eyes and face recognition
where can i find databes of pictures? like a databe with eyes of the same dimension - for example

Answer (score 2):

Here's a list of face-recognition databases http://www.face-rec.org/databases/

and here's a second list of all kind of object databases, including faces:
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cil/v-images.html

Comment: This company seems to do faces with the eye coordinates as metadata http://www.bioid.com/support/downloads/software/bioid-face-database.html

Answer (score 0):

this is another one:
http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/~vidit/IndianFaceDatabase/